# Erro migrate Laravel Sqlite

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

Ao rodar o comando Migrate ele da esse seguinte erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo da primeira migrate:

```
` public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contatos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nome');
            $table->string('tel');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Segunda migrate:

```
`public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('produtos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('titulo');
            $table->string('descricao');
            $table->decimal('valor',5,2);
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }`
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nos dois métodos está tentando criar a coluna id duas vezes, uma no início e outra no final, não é permitido duas colunas com o mesmo nome em uma tabela.

Tente realizar a execução dessa forma:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('contatos', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->string('nome');
      $table->string('tel');
      $table->string('email');
      $table->timestamps();
   });
}

public function up()
{
   Schema::create('produtos', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->string('titulo');
      $table->string('descricao');
      $table->decimal('valor',5,2);
      $table->timestamps();
   });
}
```